# need to implement Haskell's flip for Proc

Tags: ruby, haskell, functional-programming

Haskell's Prelude has a useful function that swaps a function's arguments: http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/flip_f.html

I need to do the same in Ruby. Instead of just defining a custom method, I would like to monkey patch the `Proc` class so that I could use `flip` alongside `Proc#curry`. Something like

```
f = lambda {|x, y| [x, y]}
g = f.flip.curry.(2)
```

to supply a value for `y`.

I do not know how to reopen `Proc` class to do that.

Comment: I am confused about the `curry` bit, aren't they orthogonal matters? you can try to flip the arguments of a proc regardless you want to curry it or not afterwards.

Comment: this is correct. currying and flip are independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Proc
  def flip
    lambda { |x, y| self.(y, x) }
  end
end


f = lambda { |x, y| [x, y] }
f.flip.(1, 2)
#=> [2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Proc
    def flip
        lambda { |*args| self.curry[*args.reverse] }
    end
end 

plus = lambda {|a, b, c| a + b + c }
p plus['A', 'B', 'C'] # => "ABC"
p plus.flip['A', 'B', 'C'] # => "CBA"
p plus.curry['A']['B', 'C'] # => "ABC"
p plus.curry['A'].flip['B', 'C'] # => "ACB"
```

**Update:**

```
# intermediate transformations
plus.flip.curry['a']
lambda {|a, b, c| a + b + c }
# flip
lambda {|c, b, a| a + b + c }
# curry 'a', still a Proc because of currying
lambda {|b, c| 'a' + b + c }
```

Comment: thanks. I was thinking to have something like this. This does not work with Proc#curry and partial application unfortunately.

Comment: I think it should work now, I updated the example with a curried-and-flipped proc.

Comment: `plus.flip.curry['a']` returns the partially applied Proc which takes two parameters. Try `plus.flip.curry['a']['b', 'c']` which yields `abc`. I updated the example to show the actual steps.

Comment: thanks! I did not notice the call to curry in the definition of flip. I was trying without it.

Comment: one more problem:

f = lambda {|x, y| [x, y]}
g = f.flip.(1)
p g.(2) #=> [1,2]

I expected [2,1]. I cannot figure out why.